# Write a method that takes a number as an argument and returns that number of stars on a single line

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby and would like guidance on this problem:

> Write a method that takes a number as an argument and returns that
>   number of stars on a single line
>
> For example, an input of 5 returns:
>
> ---
>
> Then, call the method with any number

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow community does not help finish homework. Please show your efforts by providing some code with the actual output you're expecting and result that you get from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def stars(number)
  puts '*' * number
end
```

In Ruby, you define a method using the **def** keyword. `stars` is the name of the method we're defining and `number` is a parameter representing the number of times the star will be displayed. `puts` is a method that take a string as a argument and prints it to the console along with a new line after the output. `'*'` (notice the single quotes) is a literal string of length one containing the asterisk character. `*` (notice the lack of quotes) is actually a string method that repeats a string a number of times specified by the integer passed to it (in this case, `number`). The `end` keyword completes the method definition, so to use this method you would just do something like `star(5)`.